# how to set always selected first row ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I was looking for this function thru api and tutorial but found only select the first row in the first grid init,

```
 gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
```

I was trying to use this capability inside `onRegisterApi` or inside filter function

```
     $scope.filter = function() {
            $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
            $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
        }

       $scope.singleFilter = function( renderableRows ){
           var matcher = new RegExp($scope.filterValue);
           renderableRows.forEach( function( row ) {
               var match = false;
               [
                   // 'id',
                   // 'study.name',
                   'title',
                   'occuredDate',
                   // 'eventType.name',
                   'description',
                   'createdDate' ,
                   // 'priority.name',
                   'severity.name',
                   'status.name',
                   'createdDate'
               ].forEach(function( field ){
                   if (field.indexOf('.') !== '-1' ) {
                       field = field.split('.');
                   }
                   if ( row.entity.hasOwnProperty(field) && row.entity[field].match(matcher) || field.length === 2 && row.entity[field[0]][field[1]].match(matcher)){
                       match = true;
                   }

               });
               if ( !match ){
                   row.visible = false;
               }
           });
           return renderableRows;
       };
```

but nothing helps. I need that first row always been selected even if I'm filtering data thru columns filter or with using single Filter. Is it possible in ui-grid?

[**my plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y06Di6YKkiMMEIUjx32y?p=preview)

Comment: plunker not working
Try to debug

 if ( row.entity.hasOwnProperty(field) && row.entity[field].match(matcher) || field.length === 2 && row.entity[field[0]][field[1]].match(matcher)){
                       match = true;
                   }
Is it comes true?

Comment: @Vitalii please check again, the plunker works fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your `gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged`-Function:

`gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);`

This way row number 1 will always be selected.

A forked plunkr: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ioa8xGLP29GyVzcvHgdH?p=preview)

Edit:

When the first record should be always visible, add the line `renderableRows[0].visible = true;` to your filter function right before the return: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ab3bPdt9xknQBcv1tZvb?p=preview)

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work, after filtered data the first row isn't selected

Comment: Well for me it works. When I have selected nothing else then row nr 1 and start filtering, the selected row count stays at 1. So the selected rows do not change when filtering the data.

Comment: My bad, I might wrong explain.. if you did filter the selected row should be first in filtered data.

Comment: Ah so you want the first row always to be shown, not selected?

Comment: no, for example open plunk in global search put "by" and push button, you will see 4 records, I want that the first record was selected

Comment: When the first record should be always visible, add the line `renderableRows[0].visible = true;` to your filter function right before the return. http://plnkr.co/edit/Ab3bPdt9xknQBcv1tZvb?p=preview

Comment: @Oliver wouold you have a look to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201642/angular-ui-grid-line-selection-is-not-working) please.