# Angular ui-grid line selection is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to select the first rendred line using Angular ui-grid but it's not working.
Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jfKdhKZRc6lpUtTvewik?p=preview) with the example.
I was able to do it using timeout after rendering data from the server but not using `$scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);` as shown in different example.
would you please help me fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is getting loaded by an async call you can select the rows in the callback, you can use $scope.gridApi since you saved it in the onRegisterApi function.

Please find the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zjSd3mcwPVpuKt7kcIB5?p=preview)

```
$http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
        $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
        $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
    });
```